# C++ initialize variable with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    static bool temp([]{ 
        cout <<"Hi ";
        return false;});


   cout <<"temp "<< temp;

   return 0;
}
```

It does not execute lambda. But if we declare lambda separately like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []{ 
        cout <<"Hi ";
        return false;};

    static bool temp(lambda());


   cout <<"temp "<< temp;

   return 0;
}
```

It will execute it. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not calling it in the first example.

Comment: Try changing `[]` to `[=]` and see what happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to invoke the lambda, just as the 2nd code snippet does.

```
static bool temp([]{ 
    cout <<"Hi ";
    return false;}());
//                ^^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3XJez7n3g1VoIZQf)

---

PS: In the 1st code snippet `temp` will always be initialized as `true`, because [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) without capture list could convert to function pointer implicitly; which is a non-null pointer and then could convert to `bool` with value `true`.